# How to check $f(x,y)=(f_1 (x,y), f_2 (x,y))$ is a diffeomorphism?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Say you are given a one-to-one mapping $f$ from the real plane to the real plane, where
$$f(x,y)=(f_1 (x,y), f_2 (x,y))$$

How do you check if f is a diffeomorphism?

Furthermore how do you restrict the domain so that it becomes a diffeomorphism if it wasn't already one?

I know $f$ is a diffeomorphism if $f$ and its inverse is continuous and differentiable.

Suppose $f$ is continuous everywhere except points $P_1,P_2,...,P_n$.
If the Jacobian determinant of $f$ is non-zero for all points excluding $P_1,P_2,...P_n$ then $f$ is a homeomorphism on this new domain?

To show differentiability you need to check the continuity of the first partial derivatives of $f_1$ and $f_2$ with respect to $x,y$?

Finally, say $f$ is continuous on the real plane except the points $P_1,P_2,...,P_n$ and suppose:

$$\text{ the first partial derivatives of } f_1 \text{ and} f_2 \text{ are only continuous when } $$
$$(x,y) \text{ is not the points } P_1,P_2,...,P_n,A_1,A_2,...,A_k$$

Then $f$ is differentaible on the original domain take away these points?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: A one-dimensional example might help you to clear up the idea of "throwing away" points where the Jacobian is zero, and specifically whether doing this necessarily gives us a diffeomorphism.  The problem is when you change the domain, the codomain is presumably going to change as well, and you might have problems with that change.  Are we asked to assume the original map is a homeomorphism?

Comment: In response to your last question: no.

Comment: I am unsure whether I get what you are saying with the "throwing away" points concept

Comment: I meant that by removing points from the domain you are "throwing them awsy", and if the result of discarding them from the domain yields a space not isomorphic to the original (plane), the we'd have to hope it discards a suitable subset of the codomain that we wind up with a homeomorphism.  I'll post an Answer to show what can go wrong.